# Django forms get request user

Tags: django, django-forms

I am building using Django and now when someone tries to post something it makes him choose which user to make the post with. how can I make the value of **author** same as the **request user**. this is the form code.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "author", "body", "header_image")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "author": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "body": forms.Textarea(
                attrs={"class": "form-control", "rows": 4, "cols": 15}
            ),
        }
```

and the view code

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "post_new.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blogs:posts")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the [`get_initial()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method in your `CreateView`. For example:

```py
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "post_new.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blogs:posts")

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['author'] = self.request.user
        return initial
```

The output of method is then passed to `PostForm` by the `FormMixin` that `CreateView` inherits from i.e. `PostForm(initial=initial)`.

And to make the `author` field hidden in your `PostForm` you can use a [`HiddenInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) widget:

```py
widgets = {
    ...
    "author": forms.HiddenInput(),
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works but still a select field with initial value of the request user. I want to make it like read only or just passed to author without showing

Comment: Yep that's easy enough. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `request.user` to ModelForm and use them in save method like this

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user: Account = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        post = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            post.author = self.user     
            post.save()
        return post



class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["user"] = self.request.user
```

Also you should remove `author` field from form

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "body", "header_image")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "body": forms.Textarea(
                attrs={"class": "form-control", "rows": 4, "cols": 15}
            ),
        }
```

Comment: I am getting an error "ModelFormMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping"